# Undergraduate 3rd year - Advice needed Physics Major

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, undergraduate, physics, major

I needed some help/advice. Would be really grateful, appreciate any advice or information.

I am a Math Major at Dickinson College. I am also taking lots of courses in Physics and Philosophy. At this point, which is the fall semester of my junior year, I have:

- 3 more courses left to complete my Math major. I still need to take Abstract Algebra, a Senior Seminar on Topology/Complex Analysis, and a 300 level elective - I'm thinking of a course on Computability and Complexity. So far in addition to the basic requirements for the major up to Real Analysis, I've also taken some additional electives. I love most of the courses so far.
- 3 more courses left to complete a major in Philosophy. I kept taking Philosophy courses just out of interest - things like Philosophy of Mind, Modern Philosophy, and Logic, and turns out at this stage I only have 3 more left to major. I'm interested in two more courses: Metaphysics and Epistemology, so I'd only have the Senior Seminar left to complete a major - so I'm strongly considering that possibility.
- 5 more courses left to complete the Physics Major. I've taken classes up to the Upper-level Dynamics and Chaos class after the Sophomore year classes in Modern Physics and Mathematical Methods in Physics. I plan to take the Upper-level QM course next semester, the ElectroDynamics course next fall and probably the Thermodynamics course the spring after. That way I'd have taken all the upper-level courses - all that'd remain is a two-semester senior year project-based seminar.

That's where my dilemma is. I can technically fit in all of these and do a triple major - while still having 1 more room for an elective. But I could also choose not to add the Physics major, while still completing all the upper-level courses.

I never intentionally aimed for a triple major or multiple minors. It just happened in the process of selecting the most interesting classes each semester. I've since discovered that I like understanding the general principles and abstractions by which we can describe the world at a fundamental level - hence the love for Math, Philosophy, Physics (I also hold some interest in Computer science in which I'm currently taking a class since it's so powerful and useful in thinking about the world). I like understanding the theorems we apply to problems at a deep level so I like my Math classes. I like seeing them applied to spit out facts about the world in my Physics classes. Then I like seeing the broader picture in all these in my Philosophy classes.

So I'd describe myself as a theorist. As far as Physics is concerned, I'm happy to take the upper-level courses. But I definitely don't want to go to Pure Physics grad school or experimental Physics grad school -- if I do it'll either be in Theoretical Physics or Mathematical Physics. I do like conceiving of and reading about experiments, but haven't really liked my labs so far - it's just a lot of tedious handiwork and teamwork.

So I'm thinking - should I really do the senior, faculty-supervised, lab-based seminar? The senior seminar will add extra work to my schedule (although manageable - I'm used to taking many and difficult classes). Plus, as more of a theoretically inclined person does it matter? Does it matter to Theoretical/Mathematical Physics grad school programs, given that I would have taken all the important course? Plus, if I don't do so I'll have the opportunity to do my own independent study - perhaps on a topic I am interested in. Or I could do research in Math, or take extra electives like Dynamical Systems, or Combinatorics or even take a few more computer science courses such as in Data Structures and Algorithms. I personally think that these additional electives are really interesting. Perhaps I should focus more on these Mathematical topics, and differentiate myself and strengthen my application in that regard. Plus I like having a balance of courses where I am taking one Physics course per semester, rather than two.

The con of that would be that I do think that the senior seminar still does offer something -- some more lab project-based research experience, which does teach or hone in certain skills. Might offer a new dimension. Might also be impressive for grad school applications. Maybe these skills are crucial even for theoretical schools. And lastly, I'm not sure if not completing the seminar, and hence not completing the major, will cause regret in the future? What kind of regret? Well, first, that of not completing the major with only 2 seminar courses left and after having completed all the upper-level courses. I'll be saying that I'm a Physics minor despite having taking pretty much all the upper-level courses. Will that stop me from Physics-related jobs in the future, or will it make me less credible for talking about Physics? I've always been interested in Physics since my childhood. A major seems like an identity of sorts. Completing a major now would be easier than say, having to find a way to do it later in case there's regret.

In an ideal world, I'd take an extra year to complete it, or maybe in an ideal world I wouldn't need to bother about it, but given reality, I wonder how I should think about this potential additional major. Maybe I should push for an extra year to graduate? I don't know.

Comment: Please shorten your question.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. We generally close questions that are so specific that the answers would only apply to you personally; so, I suggest you try to "boil down" your question to something that could be applicable to other, future readers. My 2 cents: (1) if you want to go to physics grad school, you probably want to get the physics degree. Downgrading math or philosophy to a minor makes more sense. (2) I would not recommend spending the time or money on another year of undergrad.

Comment: Full agree with @cag51 on both counts. Go have a nice talk with the physics chair as well as your math chair. Ask what students have done in the past, and do your plans make sense given what you think you want to do. I know the physics profs are nice people, and interested in having successful students.

Comment: Philosophy, Math and Physics? What are your goals after the graduation. That should be the main factor behind your decisions.

Comment: Talk to your academic advisor.  We are useless.

Comment: This sounds a lot like my undergraduate work, although I was a bit more advanced in math (having essentially finished an undergraduate degree while in high school). I eventually learned, despite not wanting to admit it, that I was awful at physics, but before this I thought the mathematical foundations of QM would be the perfect fit for me (indeed, two years in graduate school with this intention under someone who was simultaneously in roughly these 3 departments), but it wasn't. Maybe something [like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=Barry+simon+quantum+mechanics) would work for you?

Comment: (1) Get your degree in 4 years - nothing is worth an additional $70k for a fifth year at Dickinson. (2) There is a weird vibe at Dickinson about competing to get multiple degrees - ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

> I never intentionally aimed for a triple major. [...] I'm not sure if not completing the seminar, and hence not completing the major, will cause regret in the future? Will that stop me from Physics-related jobs in the future, or will it make me less credible for talking about Physics? A major seems like an identity of sorts. Maybe I should push for an extra year to graduate?

Don't let major requirements determine your life. Your first priority is to figure out the one or two majors you definitely want to complete, and your second priority is to figure out what other classes you're actually interested in taking. Spending all your time checking boxes for a triple major is pointless, and you really shouldn't wrap up your personal identify with arbitrary credentials.

From a practical point of view, it doesn't matter. If you don't go into physics, the difference between a physics major and physics minor is immaterial, given your other majors. If you do go into physics, doing the bare minimum for a physics major is not going to be enough anyway. And from an idealistic point of view, getting a deep understanding of a subject has little to do with whether you checked off all the boxes on a list. If you want to learn more about physics after college, you can simply buy books and start reading.

Comment: I like this idea of "get your degree and take other classes that interest you".

Comment: That misses the "get your degree" part, but I'm glad you're happy with the outcome!